# How to make ListView look like flowing?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView and it adds an item per second dynamically in C# WPF. Since I feel it will get stuck after thousands of items I clear it when it holds more than 100 items.

But then it doesn't look good and disappears all of a sudden. Is there a way by code to make it look like items continuously flowing? How can I delete a particular item when it reaches to 100 items so the items would look like flowing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding new items check how many are already there and remove some (the oldest ones in the beginning) to stay under limit:

```
int limit = 100;

while(myListView.Items.Count >= limit)
{
    myListView.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
myListView.Items.Add("new item");
```